# How to sort a list by the property of an object

Tags: c#, list, sorting

How to sort ascending this `List<ABC>` by `c1` element? Thank you very much!

```
public class ABC
{
    public string c0 { get; set; }
    public string c1 { get; set; }
    public string c2 { get; set; }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<ABC> items = new List<ABC>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        items.Add(new ABC
        {
            c0 = "1",
            c1 = "DGH",
            c2 = "yes"
        });
        items.Add(new ABC
        {
            c0 = "2",
            c1 = "ABC",
            c2 = "no"
        });
        items.Add(new ABC
        {
            c0 = "3",
            c1 = "XYZ",
            c2 = "yes"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: sort on basis of which field?

Comment: @AppDeveloper: I want to sort this List by c1 field. Can you help me how to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.c1);
```

This returns an `IEnumerable<ABC>`, if you need a list, add a `ToList`:

```
List<ABC> sortedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.c1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<ABC> _sort = (from a in items orderby a.c1 select a).ToList<ABC>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like :

```
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(itm => itm.c0).ToList();  // sorted on basis of c0 property
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(itm => itm.c1).ToList();  // sorted on basis of c1 property
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(itm => itm.c2).ToList();  // sorted on basis of c2 property
```

Comment: Adding a comment on the question that links to your answer is not constructive. Please delete this comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
.OrderBy(x => x.c1);
```

(or `.OrderByDescending`)

Yeah, LINQ makes it that easy.